# Chef Recipe to set hostname of an EC2 instance AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, hostname, chef-recipe

I want to write a chef recipe that will set the hostname of the EC2 instance as :

```
AWSRegionInstanceTyperandomNo
```

like `awsedev001`

how can I do this in a chef recipe? Do we have any recipe for that ?

Please help

Answer (score 2):

How would you do this in regular Unix land?

You would first add the full FQDN to `/etc/hostname` for persistence:

```rb
file '/etc/hostname' do
  content 'hostname.example.com'
end
```

Then you would set the hostname for the currently running os:

```rb
execute 'hostname hostname.example.com' do
  not_if 'hostname -eq "hostname.example.com"'
end
```

---

This is a simple Chef recipe example, but it can be made more complex to suit your needs. You may also want to look at the [hostname cookbook on the Chef community site](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/hostname).

Comment: I have modified my question according to my requirement. please help me out how to do this

Comment: I am very new to chef do not know how to do all this

Comment: Hey i have a query should I install a separate ruby for chef or should use a ruby that comes shipped with chef ?

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions on the same posting.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS in order to change the hostname you need to edit

```
/etc/sysconfig/network

NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=ip-172-16-1-23.ec2.internal
NOZEROCONF=yes
```

After editing the second line you can reboot and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef_hostname cookbook off of the community site.

In your cookbook metadata.rb just declare:

```
depends "chef_hostname"
```

And then in your recipe code use the hostname resource to set the hostname:

```
hostname "foo.example.com"
```

Or:

```
hostname node.name
```